# How to use dimensionless amount in jscience?

Tags: java, jscience

In the API [docs](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/physics/amount/Amount.html#valueOf(long,%20javax.measure.unit.Unit)) it's said that the Amount class has method valueOf.

But I don't know how to use it in.

I need to create Amount of some dimensionless quantity. Like, you know, 5 apples.

```
Amount.valueOf(100, new Unit<Dimensionless>()
```

Comment: "5 apples" is *not* dimensionless. It has units "apples". "5" is dimensionless.

Comment: Umh... Ok. What code would look like if I would need to divide 5 apples by 5?

Comment: @user1685095 Use `Amount.divide(long divisor)` ?

Comment: Yeah... But how to create 5 apples it the first place?